# How can I temporarily add/trust a certificate authority for my program?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, certificate-authority

Our program needs to work with a third party certificate that was provided by a partner.  This certificate requires we install a certificate authority that was also provided to us before connecting to the client server.  Essentially we have to work with a self signed certificate.

The application is written in C#. I could just instruct end users on how to install a certificate authority before running our application but ideally I'd like to just temporarily add/trust the certificate authority .pfx file and embed that file as a resource in the .exe.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: What method are they using the connect to their server? If they are using a method that allows customization via the config file you can do something. Otherwise you would need to change the application code to look somewhere other than the certificate store on the local machine.

Comment: Maybe put in a #if DEBUG statement and then launch certutil command line if in DEBUG?

Comment: Wouldn't you just install the certificate as part of your application install process rather than making it a temporary thing?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought (as mentioned in the comments) would be to use Process.Start() inside of a #if DEBUG conditional compilation (or use your own custom variable) to run certutil. See this article for how to install the third party CA with certutil: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295663

> To import a CA certificate into the Enterprise NTAuth store, follow
>   these steps: Export the certificate of the CA to a .cer file. The
>   following file formats are supported: DER encoded binary X.509 (.cer)
>   Base-64 encoded X.509 (.cer) At a command prompt, type the following
>   command, and then press ENTER: certutil -dspublish -f filename
>   NTAuthCA

Process.Start() documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx

You could also just write a bacth file to install and uninstall and include it in your source control or project with a readme.